# Fill stat_ecdf with two different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian

I'm doing for class hypothesis contrast with bayesian models. And I want to do a fancy graphic with ggplot showing the two hypothesis regions with two different colours.

[Normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AsqY.png)

**I would like to fill region H1 with different colour of region H0.**

My code is:

```
#Param of normal distribution
param1 <- 1.74
param2 <- 0.000617

#Normal simulation
sim_posteriori <- data.frame(rnorm(1000, param1, sqrt(param2)), rep('Posteriori', 1000))
names(sim_posteriori) <- c('Datos', 'Grupo')

#Hypotesis contrast
# P(H0) -> mu <= 1.75
pnorm(1.75, param1, sqrt(param2))
# P(H1) -> mu <= 1.75
1 - pnorm(1.75, param1, sqrt(param2))

#Plot
sim_posteriori %>% ggplot(aes(Datos)) +
  stat_ecdf(fill = '#F2C14E95', geom = 'density') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1.75), lty = 2, size = 1) +
  labs(title = 'Distribución posteriori y acumulada') +
  xlab('Altura(en metros)') + 
  ylab('Densidad') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  annotate('text', x = 1.735, y = 0.25, label = 'Región H1') +
  annotate('text', x = 1.79, y = 0.25, label = 'Región H0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find yourself wondering how to get ggplot to do a complex manipulation of your data with its various `stat_` functions, you're probably approaching your problem in the wrong way. These functions exist to make it easy to carry out common simple transformations, but we need to remember that ggplot is a tool for *plotting*, not for wrangling data, so if the `stat_` functions aren't quite what you are looking for, it's normally best to just prepare the data you actually want to plot, then plot it.

In this case it is pretty trivial to to create your own ecdf in a data frame outside of ggplot, label which parts of it are above and below your threshold, then use `geom_area` to plot it:

```r
h  <- sort(sim_posteriori$Datos)
df <- data.frame(x = h, y = seq_along(h)/length(h), region = h > 1.75)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = region)) +
  geom_area() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1.75), lty = 2, size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#F2C14E95', '#C14E4295'), guide = "none") +
  labs(title = 'Distribución posteriori y acumulada',
       x = 'Altura(en metros)', y = 'Densidad') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  annotate('text', x = 1.735, y = 0.25, label = 'Región H1') +
  annotate('text', x = 1.79, y = 0.25, label = 'Región H0')
```

[image]

Comment: You're rigth i was aproching wrong the proble. thank you!